# MLE of $\alpha=\frac{a}{\mu}+\frac{a}{\mu^2}$ given pdf $f(x;\mu)=\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{2\pi x^3}}\exp\{-\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{x}-\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{x}})^2\}$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

$n$ is a positive integer, and $\mu$ is a real number. Observations $X_1,...X_n$ are independent and each of them follows $$f(x;\mu)=\begin{eqnarray}
  \left\{
    \begin{array}{l}
      \frac{\mu}{\sqrt{2\pi x^3}}\exp\{-\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{x}-\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{x}})^2\} \quad(x\gt0) \\
      0 \quad(x\leq0)
    \end{array}
  \right.
\end{eqnarray}$$

$\alpha=\frac{a}{\mu}+\frac{a}{\mu^2}$

What is a MLE of $\alpha$, $\hat{\alpha}$?

I am allowed to use $S_n=\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_\limits{i=1}^n \frac{1}{X_i}\right)^{-1}$.

---

What I have tried

$$L=\frac{\mu^n}{(2\pi x^3)^\frac{n}{2}}\exp\{-\frac{1}{2}\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n(\sqrt{x_i}-\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{x_i}})^2\} 
\\\ l=n\log \mu -\log(2\pi x^3)^\frac{n}{2}+\{-\frac{1}{2}\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n(\sqrt{x_i}-\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{x_i}})^2\} $$

and led $$\mu=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4\alpha}}{2\alpha}$$

Then I substituted it $$l=n\log \frac{1+\sqrt{1+4\alpha}}{2\alpha} -\log(2\pi x^3)^\frac{n}{2}+\{-\frac{1}{2}\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n(\sqrt{x_i}-\frac{\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4\alpha}}{2\alpha}}{\sqrt{x_i}})^2\} \\\ = n\log (1+\sqrt{1+4\alpha})- n \log{2\alpha} -\log(2\pi x^3)^\frac{n}{2}+\{-\frac{1}{2}\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n(\sqrt{x_i}-\frac{\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4\alpha}}{2\alpha}}{\sqrt{x_i}})^2\}$$

but I could not get to the conclusion after setting this. $$\frac{\partial l}{\partial \alpha}=0 \\\ $$

Comment: It would be easier to fine the MLE of $\mu$ and then plug in that estimator to find the MLE of $\alpha$:  $\hat{\alpha}=a/\hat{\mu}+a/{\hat{\mu}}^2$.

Comment: The $\mu$ must be positive according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Gaussian_distribution#Single_parameter_form. Now use the hint above.